# Expect send to other process

Tags: tcl, expect

I have a expect script which does the following:

Spawns a.sh -> a.sh waits for user input

Spawns b.sh -> runs and finishes

I now want to send input to a.sh but having difficulties getting this working.

Below is my expect script

```
 #!/usr/bin/expect
    spawn "./a.sh"
    set a $spawn_id
    expect "enter"

    spawn "./b.sh"
    expect eof

    send -i $a "test\r"
```

a.sh is

```
read -p "enter " group
echo $group
echo $group to file > file.txt
```

and b.sh is

```
echo i am b
sleep 5
echo xx
```

Comment: Do you need to capture the output of b.sh and send any of it as input to a.sh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, `expect` will work with two feasible commands such as `send` and `expect`. In this case, if `send` is used, then it is mandatory to have `expect` (in most of the cases) afterwards. (while the vice-versa is not required to be mandatory)

This is because without that we will be missing out what is happening in the spawned process as `expect` will assume that you simply need to send one string value and not expecting anything else from the session.

After the following code

```
send "ian\n"
```

we have to make the `expect` to wait for something afterwards. You have used `expect eof` for the spawned process `a.sh` . In a same way, it can be added for the `b.sh` spawned process as well.

"Well, then why `interact` worked ?". I heard you.

They both work in the same manner except that `interact` will expect some input from the user as an interactive session. It obviously expect from you. But, your current shell script is not designed to get input and it will eventually quit since there is no much further code in the script and which is why you are seeing the proper output. Or, even having an `expect` code alone (even without `eof`) can do the trick.

Have a look at the [expect's man page](http://www.tcl.tk/man/expect5.31/expect.1.html) to know more.

Answer (score 0):

I've just got this working using

```
spawn "./a.sh"
set a $spawn_id
expect "enter"

spawn "./b.sh"
expect eof

set spawn_id $a
send "ian\n"

interact
```

My question now is why do you need interact at the end?

Comment: That would be a [different question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), yes?